# what does this mean in adb? "Note: log switch off, only log_main and log_events will have logs!"

Tags: switch-statement, adb, logcat

when using adb to extract logcats on my Hhuawei Ascend P6 I get that note, and I see that many of my log statements are not present in the log.

what is the log switch and how do I turn it on?

Comment: The USB Debugging in Developer options has to by on.

Answer (score 14):

From http://fanli7.net/a/bianchengyuyan/C__/20140325/483203.html (Chinese)：

1. In the app, Phone, dial `*#*#2846579#*#*`. You may enter ProjectMenu.
2. According to the referenced link, you should do the following thing on 8813 and then reboot

   ProjectMenu -> Background Settings -> LOG Settings -> Log Settings -> Turn on

And I do the folllwing on ALE-TL00:

```
Background Settings -> LOG Settings -> Log Settings -> turn on AP Log
```

It works

Comment: I followed your steps and i can confirm the switch is 'ON' in the popup, but
unfortunately, the response in ADB is the same error message that the switch is off.

also, there is no option for 'turn on AP log'

Comment: I've try the steps on HUAWEI P6-U06, it pops a dialog for the last step with two options: **Log on** and **Log off.** To choose **Log off,** it'll reboot.

Moreover, you should also enable **USB Debug** in **Developer options.** After that it works.

Comment: With P9 Lite, had to got in Background Settings > Log Settings. Also had to use `adb logcat` and not `adb shell logcat`

Comment: What do you mean with `8813`?

Answer (score 1):

check if this file exist:
**/dev/hwlog_switch**

if exist, use this command to turn on log:

> echo 1 > dev/hwlog_switch

if not exist, check if this file exist: **/sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable**

if exist, use this command to turn on log:

> echo 1 > /sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable

if not exist again, I can't help you than...

Comment: unfortunately, 'hwlog_switch' doesn't exist and neither does 'logger/' as per your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This error happen to me just now after I pull from git. The log works fine before with `*#*#2846579#*#*` settings.

I tested with new project and it got log, only this old project has issue. I tried rebuild the app, re-enable the log via `*#*#2846579#*#*`, and even reboot phone, but still no luck.

Then I **uninstall the app manually** (Or all relevant `productFlavors` apps) in phone and rerun, the log was back.